# Backbone.js: Template variable in element attribute doesn't work

Tags: backbone.js

I have the following template:

```
<a href="{{test_url}}>Test</a>
```

But it doesn't work, instead the {{}} becomes html encoded in the output.

How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming you are using the default templating engine that comes with Backbone.js (which actually comes from Underscore.js), then the syntax would be:

```
<a href="<%= test_url %>">Test</a>
```

Assuming that `test_url` exists in the data object you are passing to the template.  Also, make sure that you are passing a plain old JS object (`this.model.toJSON()`) to the template function or else the resolution won't happen.

If it turns out you are using a different templating engine, please let us know what engine it is AND provide us with the view code that is rendering the template.

Comment: I'm using backbone and underscore and I'm passing a json object to the template. I can't use <% %> tags because it's a .NET page. Instead I have to use ${} tags but the problem is that they become encoded for some reason.<a href="${test}.aspx">test</a> becomes <a href="%7Btest%7D.aspx">test</a>. Anything inside a attribute with quotes gets encoded.

Comment: Gotcha... so you are using the interpolation overrides that Underscore allows for?  http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#template

Comment: So, next, how are you defining your template?  Are you doing it inline in a `script` tag?  Or are you using an an external template asset?  If it is in a `script` tag, look at your source.  Is ASP.Net munging the template before it ever gets to Backbone.js?  Can you show us any more code?

Comment: I have my template defined in a script tag (easier that way). I can't use the underscore <%%> cause it's a .NET page. I used firebug and confirmed that the template variables are rendered <a href="{{test}}"></a>. However, when I use this.template.tmpl(this.model.toJSON()), the {{}} becomes encoded. I'm also using the jQuery templates plugin from http://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl (not sure if that makes a diff).

Comment: I am still confused.  If you are not using Underscore for templating, what are you using?  If you ARE using Underscore, are you telling it to interpolate the "mustache" style tags `{{}}` like in the link I gave?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using underscore and the {{}} tags work fine aslong as it's not an attribute value. This works: <a>{{Name}}</a>. This doesn't work: <a href="{{Name}}">Name</a>. The {{Name}} in the href attribute becomes encoded into <a href="%7BName%7D">Name</a>.

Comment: Solved it, I had the template in a div tag instead of script tag.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm still confused because Underscore doesn't support "mustache" tags without overriding the interpolation pattern.  Are you sure you aren't overriding the interpolation pattern some place?  Anyways, I'm glad one of my questions helped you find your problem.

Comment: +1 for being complete in all steps needed to take, staying civil while waiting for code examples. and sticking through till the very end :)