# Backbone.js model not passing to view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-boilerplate

I'm starting out with backbone.js building my first project with backbone-boilerplate.

I have a module named Navitem with a view called `Sidebar`:

```
Navitem.Views.Sidebar = Navitem.Views.Layout.extend({
    template: "navitem/sidebar",
    tagName: 'ul',
    beforeRender: function()
    {
      var me = this;
      this.options.navitems.each(function(navitem)
      {
        //insertView from Layout datatype
        me.$el.append(new Navitem.Views.Item({
          model: navitem //select the 'ul' in sidebar view and append an Item with model navitem
        }).render().el);
      });
      return this;
    }
  });
```

When the sidebar is constructed, a collection containing many `Navitem.Model`'s are passed into it.  After debugging, `model:navitem` seems to be working correctly and passing in the right `navitem` model to the `new Navitem.Views.Item({...})`.  That class looks like:

```
Navitem.Views.Item = Navitem.Views.Layout.extend({ 
    tagName: 'li',
    template: 'navitem/default'
    events: {
      click: "navRoute"
    },
    navRoute : function()
    {
      app.router.go(this.model.get('target'));
      return this;
    }
  });
```

The template looks like `<a href="#"><%= model.get('label') %></a>`.

For some reason when I call `Item.render()` in the first code block, it whines that `model` is undefined in the view. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to what was answered here : [Backbone.js: Template variable in element attribute doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665511/backbone-js-template-variable-in-element-attribute-doesnt-work)

You need to pass the model as a plain JSON to your template (unless maybe you're using another version?)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Unfortunately it does not.  I found that this is related to backbone.layoutmanager.  It does not seem like others are having this problem, does my code look correct?

Comment: Did you try debugging into the render function? Your code looks correct but maybe if you post the Navitem.Views.Layout class we'd have a better idea.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing something similar in a program that I wrote using Backbone Boilerplate and Backbone LayoutManager.

Try adding a serialize function to your Navitem.Views.Item view:

```
// provide data to the template
serialize: function() {
    return this.model.toJSON();
}
```

and then in the beforeRender function of Navitem.Views.Sidebar:

```
beforeRender: function(){
  _.each(this.options.navitems.models, function(model){
    var view = new Navitem.Views.Item({model: model});
    this.insertView(view);
  }, this);
}
```

and the navitem/default template could look like this:

```
<%= label %>
```

This is untested code (using your views and collections) but doing this has been working for me.